# Is there any way to convert RS485 to K-line (ISO 9141)?

Tags: rs485

I'm trying to build a touch panel interface based on a [WT32-SC01 PLUS](http://www.wireless-tag.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/WT32-SC01-Plus-V1.3-EN.pdf) to control my Webasto heater. The WT32-SC01 PLUS contains an RS485 interface and I would like to know if it is possible to build a simple circuit to convert RS485 to K-line (used by Webasto).

Comment: Please link to documents describing the communication protocol and electrical interfacing used by the device you mentioned.

Comment: I just made a small research and found out that there are some dedicated Ics around like L9637 from StMicroelectronics. Only the problem this converts from TTL levels. https://www.mikroe.com/iso-9141-click

Comment: @swer, I have already checked that chip (L9637), but this is expecting as input a regular serial communication. As far as I understood, RS485 is a differential signal. I'm looking something that could convert RS485->serial. Something like CH340 for USB

Comment: @Andyaka, the documentation for the touch panel device is linked in my question. The webasto heater uses a regular K-line (iso 9141) to communicate with the heater controller. Unfortunately, there's no official documentation: Webasto did not officially support using your own controller, but many people already implemented it with Rasperry Pis or Arduino devices.

Comment: Having a deeper search (indeed ChatGPT helped me xd), I found that MAX485 could do the job. Could anyone confirm if this chip does the job?